# How to process PayPal payments in an ionic app for Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, paypal, woocommerce, ionic2

I am working on an ionic 2 app which is basically a shopping cart with Woocommerce as a backend. Things have been pretty smooth with the REST API: I can browse products and create orders for the customer in the app.

But now I am stuck with payment processing. The app will only use PayPal, and there is a [PayPal plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/paypal/) I would like to use. I haven't tested it, but it seems pretty straightforward: you pass the purchase details (price, currency, description...) and then render the PayPal UI.

I can provide all that info to the PayPal UI, but it bears the obvious question: how do I integrate it with the associated Woocommerce order? How do I make it so if the payment is successful, Woocommerce registers it as such?

The Woocommerce installation already enables PayPal. You can use PayPal in the website just fine.

Now, I am pretty sure it has something to do with PayPal's IPN. Taking a wild guess, maybe I should somehow pass the order ID to the PayPal plugin, so then the IPN will pass this same order ID to Woocommerce? Probably something like that, but I cannot find proper documentation about this.

If you search "ionic 2 woocommerce paypal" you will see a lot of people selling the source code for pretty much this same thing. I could buy one and study it, but I'd rather find documentation about this particular action.

Comment: Instead of use a plugin, why only put a common HTML button to pay?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio even so, I wouldn't know what information to pass to that button.

Comment: Can you provide a lightweight version of your implementation on Git Repo? Then we can play with it no?

Comment: @Sampath it's just a button that invokes the exact same code as the docs page: (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/) - it works perfectly fine - you can assume that Woo's order is already created (let's say it is number 50) - I just don't know how to tell PayPal to tell Woo that this payment is associated to order 50.

Comment: Sure.I'll play with it and will let you know the result.

Comment: @Voldemort is this using PayPal or Braintree plugin from woo commerce?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. If you dont want to purchase plugin, you can do it manually. For example, set the `notify_url` parameter to your site, with i.e.`pp_respond` (or whatever you want).

[image]

In your `functions.php`, put this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['pp_respond'])){
    file_put_contents(__DIR__."/my_notificationssss.txt", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. "\r\n". print_r($_POST,true) . "\r\n ------------- \r\n" , FILE_APPEND);
}
```

then make a test purchase, and along the `functions.php` file there will be a new file named `my-notificationssss.txt`, and look through that file, and find out your desired parameters to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to add the order information to the users session before sending the user to Paypal.

After the user pays via Paypal, redirect them to a "success" url (Specified in the PayPal request). When the user goes to this success url, you can then update the order in WooCommerce using the session information.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in woo commerce source code it seems like it adds it's own order ID to PayPal's invoiceNumber section.

So if you have woo commerce PayPal plugin on your site (it should IPN enabled), You can use PayPal Cordova plugin in ionic 2 by passing woo commerce order ID to invoiceNumber. Like the example below:

EDIT: Although woo commerce does add invoice number, I now believe the most important params that are passed is the `custom` param.

```
pay() {
    let payment = new PayPalPayment(this.data.price, this.data.currency, this.data.description, 'sale');
    payment.custom = JSON.stringify({ order_id: this.data.WOOCOMMERCE_ORDERID, order_key: this.data.WOOCOMMERCE_ORDERKEY });
    this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        // Successfully paid

        // Example sandbox response
        //
        // {
        //   "client": {
        //     "environment": "sandbox",
        //     "product_name": "PayPal ANDROID SDK",
        //     "paypal_sdk_version": "2.16.0",
        //     "platform": "iOS"
        //   },
        //   "response_type": "payment",
        //   "response": {
        //     "id": "PAY-1AB23456CD789012EF34GHIJ",
        //     "state": "approved",
        //     "create_time": "2016-10-03T13:33:33Z",
        //     "intent": "sale"
        //   }
        // }
    }, () => {
        // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
    });
}
```